# how to solve This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

> how should I make  this called to avoid blocking request?

```
const getLocation = async () => {

   const LOCATION_URL = 'http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=country,city,lat,lon,timezone';

   const response = await axios.get(LOCATION_URL);
   return response.data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Website secured by ssl (https) can only access resources that are also secured with ssl

Checking the [documentation](https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json) reveals that:

> 256-bit SSL encryption is not available for this free API. Please see our pro service.
> [image: screenshot]

You have a few options now:

1. Buy premium
2. Use different API provider
3. Create a backend proxy that will fetch the data and send it to you

Comment: Thanks. Do yo know another IP api provider?

Comment: @Milad.eb96 you could try out IPinfo.io

Comment: @Milad.eb96 you could try out ip2location.io too

Comment: tnx, I got that covered :)